# Facebook dynamic ads - product feed issue

Tags: facebook, feed, facebook-ads-api

I am currently trying to set up a product feed for Facebook dynamic ads, but the system keeps saying saying there is an error with "incorrectly formatted shipping". However, it is the same XML feed which I use in Google Merchant Center for Google Shopping ads (where it works with no issues). And it should be officially supported by Facebook as well.

This is how my shipping is formatted: **CZ::Česká pošta - Balík do ruky:77,00**

Is the problem with two colons in a row? Or what else should I correct?

Thanks in advance,
Hoang.

Comment: Documentation says the format is `COUNTRY:STATE:SHIPPING_TYPE:PRICE`, and lists examples `US:CA:Ground:9.99 USD` and `US:NY:Air:15.99 USD`. Not sure if the STATE part is optional; but the currency seems definitively missing in your format.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find out about the currency.

Do you think it might be because of the comma? In our country, we use comma when writing decimal numbers, thus **77,77**. However, the format suggested by documentation uses "Anglo-Saxon" system: **9.99**

Comment: Yes, that should probably be a decimal point.